# Highlight particularly interesting or fun questions, comments, answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, fun, community

I'll give an example first, and then explain. So, a comment on [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/what-is-cheap-less-that-usd50-piece-of-kit-would-make-a-good-gift-for-a-photogr/3071#3071) reads:

> I, your dashing and charming husband,
>   came onto this site a few weeks ago to
>   research an anniversary gift for you.
>   I read this entire page, including
>   this answer, and ultimately bought you
>   a book and only now just now realized
>   that you, my wife, wrote this. –
>   Michael Haren Sep 20 '10 at 2:29

Now, how fun and amazing is that?

Is there some way we can collect and highlight great things like this that happen on our site?

Comment: That's awesome! I wonder how often something like that actually happens?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it adds too much value to add this to the site software directly, however I think that it would be good to find some sort of platform to highlight some of the more awesome questions or answers. We already have the [Twitter feed](http://twitter.com/photogangle), but there has been various thoughts knocking around, on [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photographic-memories) about possibly doing a blog.

Thing is, there's little point in doing a blog *unless* there is demand to read one, and also for members of the community to write articles for it - after all, blogging is hard to get **right**.